# Frank Accessibility Enabled But Still Getting an Error

Tags: ios, cucumber, accessibility, acceptance-testing, frank

Frank was working until yesterday. I'm not sure what I did that screwed it up. In a project that I had Frank installed in and worked up until yesterday, I get a:

```
PING FAILED!!!!!...
```

Message now. So I created a new project and added Frank to test it. I get the beginning of the test output, but when it actually tries to start it says accessibility is not enabled:

```
Feature: 
  As an iOS developer
  I want to have a sample feature file
  So I can see what my next step is in the wonderful world of Frank/Cucumber testing

  Scenario:                                             # features/my_first.feature:6
      Rotating the simulator for demonstration purposes
    Given I launch the app                              # features/step_definitions/launch_steps.rb:5
      ACCESSIBILITY DOES NOT APPEAR TO BE ENABLED ON YOUR SIMULATOR. Hit the home button, go to settings, select Accessibility, and turn the inspector on. (RuntimeError)
      ./features/step_definitions/launch_steps.rb:7:in `/^I launch the app$/'
  features/my_first.feature:8:in `Given I launch the app'
    Given the device is in landscape orientation        # frank-cucumber-0.9.5/lib/frank-cucumber/core_frank_steps.rb:135
    Given the device is in portrait orientation         # frank-cucumber-0.9.5/lib/frank-cucumber/core_frank_steps.rb:149
    Given the device is in landscape orientation        # frank-cucumber-0.9.5/lib/frank-cucumber/core_frank_steps.rb:135
    Given the device is in portrait orientation         # frank-cucumber-0.9.5/lib/frank-cucumber/core_frank_steps.rb:149

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:6 # Scenario: 
  Rotating the simulator for demonstration purposes
```

The "Enable Access for Assistive Devices" checkbox in system preferences -> Accessibility is already checked. So I went to enable it on the mobile device simulator like the errors says to do (which I had never done before while it was working). I turned on the Accessibility Inspector in the simulator settings, but I still get this error. I restarted the simulator and my laptop. I still get the error. Any ideas? Thanks,

Pachun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, someone [gemified Frank for rubymotion](https://github.com/cyrusinnovation/motion-frank). It works well for me.